# How to fix 'Value a of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject' error in mergeitem in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to update name value in AsyncStorage with mergeItem method. I passed the key(timestamp) to function for that particular item.

But I am not able to store the value which is a string. The AsyncStorage consists of names as values(as strings) and timestamps as keys only.

```
updateName = async(key) => {
            if (this.state.name !== '') {  
                  await AsyncStorage.mergeItem(key, JSON.stringify(this.state.name))
                        .then( () => {
                              this.props.navigation.goBack();
                        } )
                        .catch(error => console.log(error))
            }
      }
```

Here is the error I get after calling function `updateName`

```
Value a of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Storage\AsyncStorage.js:347:24 in convertError
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Storage\AsyncStorage.js:119:35 in <unknown>
- ... 5 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.name` . Are you sure it has correct JSON format ?

Comment: I is just a string using AsyncStorage.setItem(Date.now().toString(), this.state.name). Date is key and name is just a string.

Comment: Can you log the name and the key. Because it is merge into an object so I can assume that after merge the object is not a valid JSON so it can't converted.

Comment: Yes, I could log the name and key and it appears to be string. Also typeof(name) says that it is string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JSON.stringify() need a valid json to convert into string  like:**

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };  // correct json
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);

var name = "Test" // incorrect json
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(name);   // will through exception
```

According to [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#mergeitem) "Merges an existing key value with an input value, assuming both values are stringified JSON. Returns a Promise object."

if you have to just save a string then you should not call merge string after "AsyncStorage.setItem". You have to call "AsyncStorage.setItem" to reset string.

**If you want to save value for each timestamp you can use "mergeItem"**

**Sample Code**

```
const nameObject = {
  [Date.now().toString()]: "Chris"
};
await AsyncStorage.mergeItem("NAMES", JSON.stringify(nameObject));
const getNames = await AsyncStorage.getItem("NAMES");

console.log("getNames", getNames);

const nameObject2 = {
  [Date.now().toString()]: "Harry"
};
await AsyncStorage.mergeItem("NAMES", JSON.stringify(nameObject2));
const getNamesAfterUpdate = await AsyncStorage.getItem("NAMES");

console.log("getNamesAfterUpdate", getNamesAfterUpdate);
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understood how things work. Thank you.